# 2D Indices to mathematical grid for Chess Game

Tags: c++, chess

Okay so I'm coming a LONG way in my chess game! I have a MAJOR issue though! Here is how the chess board looks in memory as indexes if I want a piece at board[4][3]:

```
y axis
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  1 
x 2
a 3
x 4     X
i 5
s 6
  7
```

I numbered the x axis to what the memory indices look like so the user sees this when they look at the screen. As My code is now, THIS is what I have to type to get the pawn at d,6: user input = wf4 which translates in the program to Board[5][3]. As you can see, I want to type wd6 and go over to d and up to six. but the program goes down 5 first and over to 3(d).

```
  1 R N B Q K B N R
x 2 P P P P P P P P
a 3
x 4
i 5         
s 6       P
  7 P P P   P P P P
  8 R N B Q K B N R
    a b c d e f g h
        y-axis
```

I have the formula in place to subtract 1 from the coordinate so if the user enters (e,8) it will look for a piece in chessBoard[4][7] but, of course this will find no piece because [4][7] is down 4 over 7. We want over 4 down 7. What I REALLY want, is over 4 up  1! So that it looks like this:

```
  8 R N B Q K B N R
y 7 P P P P P P P P
a 6
x 5
i 4
s 3
  2 P P P P P P P P
  1 R N B Q K B N R
    a b c d e f g h
       x-axis
```

Here, I should type  e, 1 and get a King. To do this I would need to find some way to make the bottom left corner to 0,0 instead of the top left corner. So basically, HOW do I d o this? How do I convert 2D array indices to a mathematical style grid?!?!
EDIT*** Okay perfect example! I was my player to input c, 6 which will pop into the input values: source.x = 2 and source.y = 6. I have code that does this. NOW what I need is to tell my board[source.x][source.y] that what the player MEANT was board[2][2]. see? And I don't see a direct formula because look at this list of inputs vs what the board needs to see using the last diagram:

- input = 1,4   array[4][1]  gets the same piece
- input = 5,7   array[1][5]  gets the same piece
- input = 2,6   array[2][2]  gets the same piece
- input = 3,7   array[1][3]  gets the same piece

so it seems obvious that the input x needs to be swapped into the array's y index. but, what about the x value?? ughhh this is so complicated

Comment: It's all a matter of perspective, really. Your first diagram shows that your mental model of a 2d array grows down and to the right, but in your hard drive there's no such thing as "down" and "right". If you want the array to grow "right" and "up", then you only need to revise your mental model (and possibly the initial placement of chess pieces, if you placed them based on your old mental model).

Comment: But, let's say I create a 2d array[8][8]. When I do the for loop to initialize it, it starts at 0 and moves down to 7, and creating an array[8] at each index. so... would I solve this by starting at 8 and moving to 0?

Answer (score 1):

Try `chessBoard[x-1][8-y]`.

That way:

- x = 1 -> x-1 = 0
- x = 8 -> x-1 = 7

And:

- y = 1 -> 8-y = 7
- y = 8 -> 8-y = 0

Just what you need.

**UPDATE**:

It seems there are some confusion in here... so let's recapitulate: there are just 8 (minimally reasonable) ways of arranging a 2D matrix: 2 `x` signs times 2 `y` signs times to switch `x`/`y` or not to switch `= 2*2*2 = 8`. You just have to pick your favourite.

First, for simplity sake, I will assume that both `x` and `y` range from `0` to `7` inclusive. If that's not the case, the correction should be trivial.

Let the array name be `b`, then you have:

1. `b[x][y]`
2. `b[x][7-y]`
3. `b[7-x][y]`
4. `b[7-x][7-y]`
5. `b[y][x]`
6. `b[y][7-x]`
7. `b[7-y][x]`
8. `b[7-y][7-x]`

Now, which one? Easy. For example, you say that when `x` increases you should move to the right... so, where is right? well, that depends on how you draw the matrix (I saw your ASCII art, but it's quite ambiguous), but from the avobe 8 options, only 2 should move as you say. Of these 2, one will have `y` up and another down. Try both and choose again.

Comment: Well, that problem I already have solved. If I'm understanding your solution correctly, then input (1,1) will give me the piece at (0,7), but still, the problem remains. The issue is that when the user selects a coordinate, he is moving **over** X  first, and then **up** Y. But the Program indexes move **down** X first, and then **over** Y. Does this make sense? Maybe I'm not explaining clear enough? Look at the board layouts I diagrammed in the original question again. The program uses x as rows and y as columns. But a mathematical grid uses x as rows and y as columns.

Comment: Also, I don't mean to come off as rude at all! It may have seemed like it in the last comment but truly I'm just as confused haha! But I already have code taking care of the actual index **number**. I'm using char variables and subtracting the correct HEX code to take care of that. Like I said, the problem I'm having is that the grid structure is completely different from mathematical grids.

Comment: Then maybe you want `chessBoard[8-y][x-1]` ?  Or `chessBoard[y-1][8-x]`

Comment: Ok, there are so many ways of arranging a grid: `+x+y +x-y -x+y -x-y +y+x +y-x -y+x -y-x`. All of them can be done changing the x/y order, the sign of x or the sign of y.

Comment: (sigh) this is so confusing... Because if I increment King.current location.x ++, he moves **down** instead of to the right. That's what I need to fix lol.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys SOOOOO much for the help I really appreciate it! I figured it out. The solution for me was to go ahead and make two Location structs. One is ChessLocation who's **x value is a char** and **y is an int**, and the other is ArrayLocation, who's **x and y values are both int values**. Then I made methods to convert between the two. The idea is to operate almost everything in my code with ChessLocations. Only when I am actually setting a piece or checking a piece at a certain location of the board will I use ArrayLocations. The conversions are as follows(also, sorry I'm not sure how to make paragraphs in this text editor...)

```
ArrayLocation ChessBoard::convertToArrayLocation(ChessLocation chessLocation)
{
    ArrayLocation location;
    location.x = 8- chessLocation.y;
    location.y = chessLocation.x - 0x61;


    return location;
}
```

And this converts back to ChessLocation

```
ChessLocation ChessBoard::convertToChessLocation(ArrayLocation arrayLocation)
{
    ChessLocation location;

    location.x = 0;
    location.y = 0;
    location.x = arrayLocation.y +0x61;
    location.y = 8 - arrayLocation.x  ;

    return location;
}
```

I could have made a Location class I suppose with two constructors that accept any value and spit out the value you need, but I'm not that savvy with c++ yet(unfortunately all of my classes have used Java...